# Extracting attachment based on key word in name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the code below to extract all the attachments in an email.

How could I extract a specific attachment if the report's name contains the key word inflow.

After extracting it and saving it to the folder, I want to change its display name to Latest Report.

```
filterStr = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%5PM INfLOW REPORT%'"
For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict(filterStr)
    If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
            oOlAtch.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & oOlAtch.DisplayName
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "The First item doesn't have an attachment"
    End If
    Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

check the existence of the keyword "inflow" in the attachment name before saving.

```
For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
    If InStr(oOlAtch.DisplayName, "inflow") > 0 Then
      oOlAtch.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & oOlAtch.DisplayName
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, do you know how i can change the name I save the file?  can i put a bracket behind display name to change the display name?

Comment: if it is an xlsx file you can remove "oOlAtch.DisplayName" and replace it with "LatestReport.xlsx" . However, then you lose information about the file i.e. in the case that the original file had descriptive naming.